# Do I still pay internet taxes

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, ecommerce

If I buy, over the internet, a gift that is going to a non-sales-tax state (OR) resident do I still pay my local (WA) sales tax?
Or, should I just drive to their place in OR and have them buy it? This would save me ~$200 in sales tax.

Comment: Typically it's about shipping location, but rules vary by state so it matters which state the company you buy from is in and/or if they have a nexus in the recipients state.

Comment: Is driving to OR worth the tax savings? How much will it cost round-trip in gas and tolls? More importantly, how much of your time would it take, and how much do you value your time?

Answer (score 4):

Washington state, where I assume you are located, looks to be a [destination-based sales tax state](https://dor.wa.gov/find-taxes-rates/retail-sales-tax/destination-based-sales-tax). From the page, emphasis added by me.

> Destination-based sales tax means that if a retailer delivers or ships merchandise to a buyer **in Washington**, the sales tax is collected based on the rate at the location where the buyer receives or takes possession of the merchandise. This only affects shipments and deliveries **to locations within Washington State**.

Thus it is most likely that you would not pay sales tax to a delivery to another state, even if you reside in WA.